# Hibernate - Rollback: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, struts2, pojo

I have written few codes for inserting data into my SQL database. Actually, I am trying to learn Struts 2 with Hibernate. But, unfortunately I am facing a problem after submitting my form.

I could not find the reason for this error message. My try & catch block throws error like:

```
Exception in saveOrUpdate() Rollback  :org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: v.esoft.pojos.Employee
```

**Pojo(`Employee.java`):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "eventusdb")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer empId;
    private String name;
    private String website;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, String website) {
        this.name = name;
        this.website = website;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return this.empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "website", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getWebsite() {
        return this.website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

}
```

**also having `Employee.hbm.xml`:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 10, 2013 4:29:04 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="v.esoft.pojos.Employee" table="employee" catalog="eventusdb">
        <id name="empId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="emp_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="website" type="string">
            <column name="website" length="65535" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: which line no. you are getting this exception?

Comment: @Aniket that only i don't know? how to know which line i am getting exception?

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` in addition to your `System.out.println()`. And for the future, use Log4J or something similar, that will parse the Exception's StackTrace for you.

Comment: @AndreaLigios This problem solved actually i have to map my POJO class,  But after running this code its not inserting my form data into the table. I am getting `1 row inserted successfully.` message but no insertion of data in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entity isn't mapped, you should inspect the hibernate configuration. Hibernate is ORM framework used to map pojos (entities) to the database schema objects. You didn't configure or hibernate couldn't find mapping for the object `Employee`. The configuration file is `hibernate.cfg.xml` should contain the mapping to the resource `Employee.hbm.xml`. Suppose this file is in the same folder as `Employee` class. Then the mapping will be

```
<mapping resource="v/esoft/pojos/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
```

Another approach if you used an annotation based configuration, then you should use `class` attribute to map to the pojo that contains Hibernate/JPA annotations.

```
<mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Employee"/>
```

Note, annotation based `Configuration` might be different depending on version of Hibernate and may require additional libraries.

Comment: Thanks i added  `<mapping class="v.esoft.pojos.Employee"/>` in my hibernate.cfg file and now this problem is solved.   But Now its not inserting into my database code.  Its not showing any error for this error. What could be the mistakes?

Comment: It could be a transaction that you are not committing, or database related.

Comment: Thanks this problem has been solved. May be you can help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742091/java-how-to-insert-row-in-a-db-table-after-reading-excel-file