# Java- how to insert row in a db table after reading excel file

Tags: java, excel, struts2, apache-poi

I am able to read the excel file data  from the below code, but I am unable to get the logic behind how to get Excel data in order to store in POJO class after reading the excel file.

In short: I am confused how to send these read Excel data to my model class to be stored in my database table?

The following code prints correctly the excel rows in my Eclipse console:

```
                     ..............
                          ..............
        public String execute()
        {
            try
            { 
                 String filePath=servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); 
                 File fileToCreate= new File(filePath,this.excelDataFileName);
                 FileUtils.copyFile(this.excelData, fileToCreate); 
                 UploadExcel obj=new UploadExcel();
                 obj.readExcel(excelData.getAbsolutePath()); 

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                addActionError(e.getMessage());
                return INPUT;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }


        /*
         *Method to read the each sheet ,row & column of the excel sheet of the uploaded xls file  
        */
        public void readExcel(String filePath)
        { 
            try
             {
                FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

                //Getting the instance for XLS file 
                 HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                 //Get First sheet from the workbook
                HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                 ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
                //Iterate start from the first sheet of the uploaded excel file
                  Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                  while(rowIterator.hasNext())
                  {
                      Row  row=rowIterator.next();

                      if(row.getRowNum()==0)
                      {
                          continue;//skip to read the first row of file
                      }

                      //For each row, iterate through each columns
                      Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();

                      while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                      {
                          Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                          if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0)
                          {
                              continue;
                          }
                          switch(cell.getCellType())
                          {
                             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                  System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                 // myList.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                                  break;
                             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                 System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "\t\t");
                                //  myList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                 break;
                             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                 System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t");
                                // myList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                 break;
                          }

                      }     
                      System.out.println(""); 


                  }
                  file.close();
                FileOutputStream out=
                        new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));

                  workbook.write(out);
                  out.close();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }




    }
```

In console output:

```
TEXTit      6695 PROSPECT RD        Nova Scotia     B3z 3t1 

row2sdfsda      61695 P         sfsdfdsf        23B3z 3t1
```

What I thought is: I have to get the row one by one and I will add this row data to my POJO class object and send it to dao, and finally use `saveOrupdate(tableobj)` of hibernate method to save the data into my db table.

But I was unable to think how I can add these pieces of data to my Pojo class.

Hope someone can help me here.

Comment: Do not send each row to your DAO one per one. It will be horrible slow..You can just pass in a List of your object type and do it in 1 clean transaction with a batch insert

Comment: @steelshark can you please post a answer as you suggested. I am learning struts2 hibernate, i could not get the things which you said in this comment.

Comment: @steelshark i written code here [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18763556/2732367) as you suggested in your comment, but it is not inserting into my db, neither it is showing any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject/pass reference to your DAO into UploadExcel class. Then when in readExcel() method you can create new ENTITY and fill it with values.

```
                  Entity entity = new Entity();


                  while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                  {
                      Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                      if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0)
                      {
                          continue;
                      }
                      switch(cell.getCellType())
                      {
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                              entity.setBooleanValue(cell.getBooleanValue);
                              break;
                         ...
                      }

                  }
```

Finally you insert/createOrUpdate your entity by your DAO.

```
                  dao.insertOrUpdate(entity);
```

***** EDIT ***** 
Code to explain comment

Entity is just an example of custom entity which models data you read from excel.
If for example your excel contains data about Customer then you can create
customer entity.

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Integer age;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    // + getters and setters for other fields
}
```

Then you send this entity filled with excel data to your DAO (which manages customer table), and insert given entity into DB.

*** EDIT2 ***

Remove "dao.saveOrUpdateCompany(company);" from following code:

```
    public String execute()
    {
        try
        { 
             String filePath=servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); 
             File fileToCreate= new File(filePath,this.excelDataFileName);
             FileUtils.copyFile(this.excelData, fileToCreate); 
             UploadExcel obj=new UploadExcel();
             obj.readExcel(excelData.getAbsolutePath());  
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

You want one new entity PER ROW, now you just create one entity in the beginning of class

Read comments following code

```
    public void readExcel(String filePath)
    { 
        try
         {
             List sheetData = new ArrayList();
            FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            //Getting the instance for XLS file 
             HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(file);

             //Get First sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate start from the first sheet of the uploaded excel file
              Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

              while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                   Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();

                   // CHANGE 
                   Company company = new Company();
                   company.setName(getCellValue(row.getCell((short)1)));

                   // HERE YOU CAN SAVE COMPANY 
                   dao.saveOrUpdateCompany(company);

                   // OR ADD COMPANY TO LIST 
                   // List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();
                   // Declare just one list for entire class not per row
                   // In this case you call custom made DAO method which batch save
                   // all company entities in list but you call this custom method
                   // at the end of excel processing (your original dao code position).
                   // Try it without list first  
                   list.add(company);    


              }



              System.out.println("Seet data size-"+sheetData.size());
              file.close();
            FileOutputStream out=
                    new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));

              workbook.write(out);
              out.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

*** EDIT3 ***

I think this should finally work

```
       try{
            session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction=session.beginTransaction();
            for(int i=0;i<companies.size();i++)
            {   
                // THIS IS BAD 
                //Company com=new Company();
                //You need this
                Company com = companies.get(i);
                session.saveOrUpdate(com);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            status++;

        }
```

Comment: From which package the `Entity` belongs to?

Comment: I used entity as an example. You will have your own custom Entity bean (POJO) e.g. Customer. So in your case you are reading values from excel so you can fill fields in your custom entity object. Customer can have fields like: name, surname, age. Then when you iterate excel cells you assign values to your entity object e.g. customer.setName(cell.getStringValue) if the cell contains customer name.

Comment: i tried same as you said, but it is inserting  many null rows with not exact data to the table column filds. Eg. it inserted name in address column and other data in diffrent column.  `If it is possible, please post almost complete code, for me. I have shown all my model,& pojo in above question`. I am new to this , trying to learn but struct here from last 2 days.

Comment: thanks this way it is working fine. But i want to do like  in second way as you suggested in your last comments like `List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();`...  Well let me try to do like this , if i have again any problem related to this,then i may ask you here...

Comment: hi, first method worked but too slow thats why i tried second way,but it is showing error `Rollback:org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList`   I tried passing  ` dao.saveOrUpdateCompany(companies);` from action and then in my DAO , i define my DAO method starting with `public int saveOrUpdateCompany(List<Company> companies){....}`  but DAO is throwing error

Comment: You declare list at begining of your class List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>(); then you add filled Company entity to that list so companies.add(company); then after Excel processing has ended you pass companies list to your DAO's custom method you have to write e.g.: public void batchInsertCompanies(List companies)... in that method you have to do Hibernate batch insert, read this [Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

Comment: Yeah i read the batch insert, i tried also as you explained ,But still it is not inserting data into my database , neighter it is showing any error.  [Here is my new code which i tried(click here)] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18763556/2732367)

Comment: Tomas , I tried third Update, but still it is not adding into my db table.

Comment: company.setName(getCellValue(row.getCell((short)1)));//going on u must  row.getCell((short)2) etc

Comment: Tomas , I tried third Update, but still it is not adding into my db table. , i tried to print `companies.size()` in the dao method, but its showing size as zero

Comment: I think from excel sheet you are not able to populate values into pojo properly.U need to iterate each row .and from each row u need to get data from each cell.

Comment: i checked it is populating the data from excel sheet, i used            `System.out.println("row name-"+company.getName());` and it is printing the valid rows of Name.  I guess there is problem while setting this company to compines list like this                          `companies.add(company);`  and i tried to print `System.out.println("row name-"+companies.get(2));` but its showing some pojo_out in some string format

Comment: You have to use it like companies.get(2).getName(), companies.get(2) gets just Company object from which you have to retreive field values

Comment: here is a two image screnshot , which will show how the data is stored in companies arraylist,  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xfOQM.png,   & http://i.stack.imgur.com/bhOYY.png

Comment: Okay its working fine, finally my problem has been solved, thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Iterator iterator = workSheet.rowIterator();
          while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         Row row = (Row) iterator.next();
// check each cell for null and by using getCellValue() method. and inject the value in to user defined pojo.
    }


 private String getCellValue(Cell cell) {
        if (cell == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            return cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
            return cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
        }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR){
            return cell.getErrorCellValue() + "";
        } 
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are try to show with your answer? It looks like you have just written a code to display excel data, which i have already written code. I want to know how can i send these data to my DAO in order to store it in my DB table. Please read my question once again

Comment: Once u pass excel data in to pojo .by using that pojo u can save data in to database using hibernate.If u need hibernate code i can give

Comment: my question is "how can i pass these data to my pojo?"   my pojo name is "Company"

Comment: From above code. after iterating each row. get value as row.getCell((short) colNum).getStringCellValue().(colnum starts from '0').if value is not null. For example : company.setTown(getCellValue(row.getCell((short) 1))));

Comment: what is `getCell((short) 1))))`?   I have updated my question above , i have added my POJO and a model method. Please help me with your answer by  more code.

Comment: It is row.getCell(1)//if u want u can remove short

Comment: As you suggested i modified my code but it is inserting null in my db table. I have shown the full code in above question at the last with nam `New update code`  . Please help

Comment: K i had seen i cant guess what excel is contains.So check in excel wheter data is there r not.If it is there check wheter which value is inserting into pojo.then there will not be any prob.

Comment: i update here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18763556/2732367 , but its not inserting data, no error showing....please help me